# How can I change the stop loss value?

Tags: pine-script

How can I change the stop loss value?

There is a stop loss code as shown below:

```
longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1-slLen/100)
strategy.exit("SL", "BUY", stop=longStopPrice)
```

If it rises more than 1% after buying, I want to change the stop loss to the entry price.

Comment: Try posting more information about your issue and possibly add more code. More context could be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it this way

```
if strategy.position_avg_price * 1.01 < close 
    longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price 
else
    longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1-slLen/100)

strategy.exit("SL", "BUY", stop=longStopPrice)
```